# Why every time Create a new record I found ID increment by 2 not in normal way?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Why every time I Create a new record I found ID increment by 2 not in normal way ?[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIhY2.png)

Comment: hows that Id get generated? plugin code? share the whole context pls

Comment: Yes using Plugin and I Found This plugin and after unregistered it now working fine no increment in ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess is that there is a workflow or plugin that is creating a duplicate, and that duplicate isn't showing in your query, or is being deleted by the plugin/workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your Guess Yes using Plugin and I found this plugin and after unregistered it now working fine with no increment in ID